# Get Diffrence between two date string in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs, date-difference

I am using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) for date and I have one date string, ie,`"2015-05-10"`,I want to get date difference from today

```
 var today= moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

How it is possible here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a example,

```
var now = moment(); // moment object of now
var day = moment("2015-05-13"); // moment object of other date

$scope.difference = now.diff(day, 'days'); // calculate the difference in days

$scope.difference = now.diff(day, 'hours'); // calculate the difference in hours
```

check more options [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

here is a [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jfMSN18bC2JQJRQ9enV5?p=preview)

Comment: I getting error that `now.diff ` not a function.. I am using in angularjs

Comment: did you check the example and the version of the moment.js

Comment: I am sorry.. it was my mistakes,Your code is working fine .. thank you  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
//Convert to date 
var today = moment();
var date = moment("2015-05-13", "YYYY-MM-DD");

//Use diff
var duration = today.diff(date);
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about `time difference in hours`

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
```

Comment: how to diff without utc ?